# What is the minimum value of $8 \cos^2 x + 18 \sec^2 x$?

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

As per me the answer should be $26$.

But when we apply AM-GM inequality it gives $24$ as the least value but as per the graph 24 can never come.

What I think is that in AM-GM, it gives $8 \cos^2 x = 18 \sec^2 x$ which gives $\cos x > 1$ which is not possible and because of this, AM-GM is giving a wrong minimum value.

If we had $18 \cos^2 x + 8 \sec^2 x$, then AM-GM would have worked and $24$ would be a right answer since $18 \cos^2 x = 8 \sec^2 x$, which gives $\cos x < 1$ which is true.

Is this reason correct?

Comment: Why don't you differentiate it?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: If you want to apply AM-GM, please write it as $8 \cos^2 x + 8 \sec^2 x + 10 \sec^2 x$. Min of $8 \cos^2 x + 8 \sec^2 x$ by AM-GM will be $16$ and min of $10 \sec^2x$ is $10$.

Comment: But how would you know the minimums of both functions occur for the same value of $x$? The minimum of $\sin x$ is $-1$, and the minimum of $\cos x$ is $-1$, but the minimum of $\sin x + \cos x$ is not $-2$.

Comment: @TobyMak of course we can show it. We know at what $x$, the equality for AM-GM occurs, when $\cos x = \sec x$.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank You!

Comment: @Algebrology yes differentiation can be done, was seeing why was AM GM not working for 8cos^2 x + 18sec^2 x. What I have realized is that AM GM gives us a lower bound which need not be true, we have to check for some conditions like in this cos x was coming >1 when we equate both of them

Comment: @AyushSambher Oh ok, I did not consider using AM-GM, instead after seeing you question, I straightaway went for differentiating it and was wondering why you aren't using differentiation. Now I understood your query :)

Comment: @MathLover why it will be wrong if we apply A.M. -G.M. on $8\cos^2(x)$ and $\18sec^2(x)$

Comment: @LalitTolani because that's a minimum we can never reach. AM-GM in itself will consider $\cos^2x$ and $\sec^2x$ as two  variables with no constraint on their values but the equality occurs at a value of $\cos x$ that does not exist for $\cos x$.

Comment: @LalitTolani since we will get 8cos^2 x + 18sec^2 x > 24 and not >= 24, so minimum value using differentiation or splitting 18sec^2 x as 8sec^2 x + 10sec^2 x and then applying AM GM on (8cos^2 x + 8sec^2 x) and minimum value of 10sec^2 x is 1 so 26 is the minimum value. But this is by chance I think, as we know sinx minimum value is -1 and same cosx has the minimum value as -1, so it doesn't mean that minimum value of sinx + cosx is -2 as Toby said above

Answer (score 1):

$$8\cos^2(x)+18\sec^2(x)=8\cos^2(x)+8\sec^2(x)+10\sec^2(x)$$

Now, apply $AM-GM$ on the first two terms.

$$\frac{8\cos^2(x)+8\sec^2(x)}{2}\ge\sqrt{8\cos^2(x)\cdot8\sec^2(x)}$$

$$\implies {8\cos^2(x)+8\sec^2(x)}\ge 16$$ at $x=0$

And min of $10\sec^2(x)$ is $10$ at $x=0$. So, the minimum of the net function is $26$ at $x=0$

Comment: @AyushSambher Thanks :) If this answers your query, you can accept the answer by clicking the small green tick on the left

Comment: Hey, I think AM GM will not work here by directly using 8cos^2 x + 18sec^2 x > 24, and then we cannot say that is sinx has a minimum value is -1 and cosx minimum value is -1, so minimum value of sin x + cos x is -2 which is not true. So isn't your method by chance correct?

Answer (score 0):

No need for AM-GM.

Differentiate wrt $x$ and set $f'(x)=0$ as follows:

$$\implies -16\sin x\cdot \cos x + 36\sec^2 x\cdot \tan x=0$$
$$4\cos x\sin x=\frac{9\sin x}{\cos^3 x}$$
If $\sin x$ is non-zero, then:
$$\cos^4 x=\frac{9}{4}\implies \cos x=±\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}>1\implies \text{no solution}$$
Hence $\sin x=0\implies \cos x=±1$ and hence $\cos^2 x=1$.

Substitute this into your original equation and you get $8+18=26.$

NOTE: You can confirm that this is a minima by evaluating $f''(x).$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, differentiation can be done, was seeing why was AM GM not working for 8cos^2 x + 18sec^2 x. What I have realized is that AM GM gives us a lower bound which need not be true, we have to check for some conditions like in this cos x was coming >1 when we equate both of them. We got 8cos^2 x + 18sec^2 x > 24 using GM which is true. Answer is 26